# Angular materials Mat-table, not working with in the html with .push

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am working on an infinite scroll in angular 8. I am using an angular materials table to display my data.

Html:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="displayOfMassSendObjects" 
   infinite-scroll
   [infiniteScrollDistance]="scrollDistance"
   [infiniteScrollUpDistance]="scrollUpDistance"
   (scroll)="onScrollDown()"
   (scrollup) = "onScrollUp()"
>

 <ng-container id = "companyNameColumn" matColumnDef="companyName">
    <mat-header-cell id = "companyNameTitle" 
           *matHeaderCellDef>CompanyName</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell class = "companyNameData" *matCellDef="let row"> 
           {{row.companyName}}</mat-cell>
 </ng-container>

 <ng-container id = "emailColumn" matColumnDef="email">
    <mat-header-cell id = "emailTitle" 
          *matHeaderCellDef>Email</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell class = "emailData" class="email" *matCellDef="let row"> 
           {{row.email}}</a></mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumns"> </mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

On load I have 10 records showing up in the table. When I scroll down, I am expecting that more records will populate in the HTML but they are not. The records are however being added to the array in the console.log(). I think the problem is that the HTML Angular Materials is not recognizing the .push because when I substitute .push for .slice, the records show up in the HTML, however don't want the app to work like that.

Here is my component for the table where I want the scroll bar:

```
 export class MassSendComponent implements OnInit {
  sum = 10; 
  globalList = []; 
  displayOfMassSendObjects: MassSend[]; 
  tableColumns : string[] = ['ispNumber','companyName', 'email', 'taxId']
  constructor(
      private mockMassSendService: MockMassSendService,
       ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getMassSendData();  
  }

 getMassSendData() {
      this.mockMassSendService.getMassSendData()
         .subscribe(massSendObjects => {
             this.globalList = massSendObjects; 
             this.displayOfMassSendObjects = massSendObjects.slice(0, 
             this.sum);
     }); 
  }

  getMoreData() {
    this.displayOfMassSendObjects.push(this.globalList[this.sum]); 
  }


 onScrollDown(): void {
   console.log(this.displayOfMassSendObjects);  
   this.getMoreData(); 
   this.sum += 1;
  }
}
```

I also have a service method being called:

```
     export class MockMassSendService {

      constructor() { }

         getMassSendData(): Observable<MassSend[]> {
             return of(mockMassSend); 
         }
      }
```

Comment: instead of push, try concat

Answer (score 1):

You can use   `displayOfMassSendObjects = new MatTableDataSource(this.displayOfMassSendObjects);` every time you fetcb new data, this will initialize a new datasource object.
The reason you are not able to see newly added rows is that 
Mat table only reflects changes when the reference to datasource is changed that's why when you use slice method it works fine.

Comment: thank you, when I do that tho, I get an error that i have to use this.displayOfMassSendObjects. Then when I do this.display... i get another error that i need push, concat ect. do you know the proper syntax? this is what i am trying to do:

Comment: getMoreData() {
      this.displayOfMassSendObjects = new MatTableDataSource(this.displayOfMassSendObjects); 
     this.displayOfMassSendObjects.push(this.globalList[this.sum])
  }

Comment: ERROR error TS2740: Type 'MatTableDataSource<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.

Comment: I can't seem to understand the error. You can see this example for reference [link]https://stackblitz.com/angular/gqlnjbagbjg?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.ts.